Preserve empty css classes in vite/post-css
How can I configure vite/post-css to include empty css classes?
.nothing {
}

import styles from './Component.module.css';
// styles is empty..

I've checked docs for both vite and post-css and don't an option.
I'm using vite-plugin-sass-dts to generate types and in development when I type out all the css classes but haven't put in the content yet the code won't compile.
